# How would I write a regular expression to match numeric or alphanumeric words, but not words without numbers?

Tags: c#, regex

This will execute in the C# Regex Engine, in the .Net Framework 4.7.2.

I need a Regular Expression to search strings for "words" that match the following properties:

- A numeric value, such as 1234, or 10.00
- An alphanumeric value, such as ABC123 or ABC10.00
- NOT an alpha-only value, such as cat or CAT
- Matches separated by any non alpha-numeric character.

Matches:  "123", "ABC123", "abc123", "10.00", "ABC.123", "Foo10.00"

Non-matches: "sugar", "rush", "XYZ"

In the following example string, the matches I want are in **bold-italic**:
***789***|--|***789*** ***ABC*** ***123*** ***10.00*** **ABC123** **123ABC** **ABC123ABC** ***abc.123.abc***

I am currently using the following regex, but it is just an aggregation of all the special cases, and doesn't cover fully-complex cases.  There must be a more efficient way to write this:

```
(?<=^|[\W])(?:[\d]+[A-Za-z]{1,}|[A-Za-z]+[\d]{1,}|[\d]+[.]+[\d]{1,}|[\d]{1,})(?=$|[\W])
```

This regex will match most of the examples above, but it will not not match any value where we toggle from numbers to letters and back, or vice-versa, like this:  A1B2C3D4.

To test:  https://regex101.com/r/oeSg10/1

Comment: It may be that regex isn't the right tool for this job (or able to do everything in one shot). You might have to split the string on spaces and get the number of letter and digit characters in each element.

Comment: `var wordsWithNumbers = input.Split(' ').Where(w => w.Any(char.IsDigit)).ToList();`

Comment: Use an OR : (A-Za-Z)+[0-9.]+|[0-9.]+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?xi)                # Enable free-spacing and case insensitive mode
\b                   # Word boundary
(?=[A-Z.]*[0-9])     # After any 0+ letters/dots there must be a digit
[A-Z0-9]+            # 1+ letters or digits
(?:\.[A-Z0-9]+)*     # 0+ repetitions of a . and then 1+ letters/digits
\b                   # Word boundary
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qenHnp/1/) at regex101.com and a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fxi%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Enable%20free-spacing%20and%20case%20insensitive%20mode%0D%0A%5Cb%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Word%20boundary%0D%0A%28%3F%3D%5BA-Z.%5D*%5B0-9%5D%29%20%20%20%20%20%23%20After%20any%200%2B%20letters%2Fdots%20there%20must%20be%20a%20digit%0D%0A%5BA-Z0-9%5D%2B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%201%2B%20letters%20or%20digits%0D%0A%28%3F%3A%5C.%5BA-Z0-9%5D%2B%29*%20%20%20%20%20%23%200%2B%20repetitions%20of%20a%20.%20and%20then%201%2B%20letters%2Fdigits%0D%0A%5Cb%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Word%20boundary&i=A%20numeric%20value%2C%20such%20as%201234%2C%20or%2010.00%0D%0AAn%20alphanumeric%20value%2C%20such%20as%20ABC123%20or%20ABC10.00%0D%0ANOT%20an%20alpha-only%20value%2C%20such%20as%20cat%20or%20CAT%0D%0AMatches%20separated%20by%20any%20non%20alpha-numeric%20character.%0D%0AMatches%3A%20%22123%22%2C%20%22ABC123%22%2C%20%22abc123%22%2C%20%2210.00%22%2C%20%22ABC.123%22%2C%20%22Foo10.00%22%0D%0A%0D%0ANon-matches%3A%20%22sugar%22%2C%20%22rush%22%2C%20%22XYZ%22) showing it really works in a .NET environment.

In C# code, you may use

```
var Pattern = new Regex(@"
\b                   # Word boundary
(?=[A-Z.]*[0-9])     # After any 0+ letters/dots there must be a digit
[A-Z0-9]+            # 1+ letters or digits
(?:\.[A-Z0-9]+)*     # 0+ repetitions of a . and then 1+ letters/digits
\b                   # Word boundary", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

where `(?x)` = `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` and `(?i)` = `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

Comment: Excellent and well-documented answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Underrated. I found so many other's that just weren't working. Thank you!